# Nodejs Terminate Spawned Child Process

Tags: node.js

I started a child process for a jar file by

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
// Start child process
var child = exec("java -jar test.jar");
```

and I terminated the child process by using a kill function that I wrote given the pid of the child

```
killProcess(child.pid);
```

The function always work when the pid is correct, however, because nodejs created the child process inside a cmd.exe shown in the picture below, 
and the child.pid is the pid for the cmd.exe not the actual java.exe

[image]

My problem is that, occasionally, the java.exe will get too large and jump out of the cmd.exe and become an independent process, and I can't terminate it even when I stop the server. And because I don't have the pid of the java.exe I can't terminate it with my function.

What other ways can I terminate the process without doing it manually, or get the pid of the java.exe and not the cmd.exe?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, the problem is with the way how I create the child process.

Creating child process with exec has a size limit, thus, change it from exec to spawn solves the problem.

```
// Spawn the external jar file as a child process and listen print the output
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
// Start child process
var child = spawn('java', ['-jar', file_name]);
```